# Add nuget folder to git repository using Visual studio 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I am new using GIT and VS2015.
How can I add existing Nuget folder in GIT repo using Visual studios 2015.?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute following commands from folder

1)  Git add  -f

2)  Git add /*

3)  Git commit

After this changes will be in Staging. Now you can commit changes normally by adding comment/ message and Push.